# least condition for the Fourier transform to be integrable

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to prove that if $f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ is compactly supported then its Fourier transform is integrable.
I was able to prove the result for $f \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and compactly supported. I used the fact that if $f \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\hat{f}$ is bounded by $\frac{c}{1+{|x|}^{2}}$. So it is integrable.
I failed to prove it if $f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Does page 4 of the following link help? http://www.math.unc.edu/Faculty/met/s14.pdf

Comment: No, but page 6 does :), thanks a lot,...
I'm trying to see now if this result can be upgraded to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: @Suvrit: The link is broke. Could you please write out the author and title of the paper?

Comment: @Suvrit Link broken.

Comment: @DenisSerre Are you sure about your comment? I am pretty sure that square integrable functions with square integrable generalised derivative have integrable Fourier transforms, as a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @coudy. Of course you're right. And this is a way to prove that $H^1({\mathbb R})\subset C^0$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to the paper about necessary conditions for the integrability of the Fourier transform:

http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/gmj/gmj16/gmj16043.pdf

It is stated in that paper that sufficient conditions for the integrability of the Fourier transform are given in the book

R. M. Trigub and E. S. Bellinsky, Fourier analysis and approximation of functions.
Kluwer Academic Publishers, Dordrecht, 2004.

Comment: The link is broke. Could you please write out the author and title of the paper?

Comment: I think the paper is: Elijah Liflyand, _Necessary Conditions for Integrability of the Fourier Transform_, Georgian Mathematical Journal, Volume **16** (2009), Number **3**, 553–559